# Two systems unable to connect while on same network

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, dd-wrt, raspbian

Having a strange issue here. I have a desktop computer and a raspberry pi 3 that are unable to connect to one another, while both can access the internet and a third laptop computer.

Desktop computer is current Windows 10, firewall is off, network discovery is on.

Raspberry pi is current Raspbian, iptables is blank.

Router is a TP-Link TL-WR841ND v9, running DD-WRT v3.0-r30949 std (12/15/16).

All systems can ping themselves, the gateway, and an internet address. All systems are set to 255.255.255.0 and all IPs are set to 192.168.1.*. The router is running default DD-WRT settings

Would greatly appreciate any assistance as I've no clue what's wrong here. I see a bunch of threads thru google speaking of similar issues that don't seem to map onto this.

Edit: Shortly after I posted this I ran this command on the router:

swconfig dev switch0 set enable_vlan 1

swconfig dev switch0 set apply

Suddenly the desktop can see the raspberry pi. Could someone explain to me why this happened?

Comment: Looks like you may have created a virtual switch with the router software and set that to vlan1 and enabled it. The router functionality must have been simply routing traffic connected to it's LAN interface(s) out to the Internet but wasn't broadcasting locally so the default gateway was sending out only and did not have switching functionality until you enabled and set the vlan but likely due to the the way the router builds its routing table based on these features and functions. Look over https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/swconfig for full detail of the applicable switches, etc.